# How to Change Joomla URL Format

Tags: url, joomla

I am working in a Joomla 2.5 site, and the article links in the main page are like this: domain/(category name)/(article name), and is causing a lot of issues.

There is a way to change it to domain/component/content/article/(category name)/(article name)?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have SEF turned on then this should show URL's such as the ones you provided in your question however some components are not SEF friendly thus will cause problems. Ensure that your components are SEF friendly, else turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your just viewing the article through the default joomla? But to do that you'll need to basically remove it from the menu! As by adding it to a menu item by default you loose the "component/content/article" part of the url, and as far as I am aware, the only way to do that would be to change the code in the router.php file in com_content. I'm not sure exactly where as I've never had to go about changing that particular file

What issues are you facing that makes adding this in so critical? Because its a standard joomla response - and most people want to remove the "component/content/article" from their url's!!